# How to check lensfun version on Fedora

Tags: darktable, linux, lensfun

I was just about to make calibration files for my Tamron 90mm SP but according to [lensfun](https://wilson.bronger.org/lensfun_coverage.html) it was added in 1.613 (there is only one SP 90mm and it's the same as the one I have in EXIF). How can I check which version I have on my Fedora? **And possibly how to update lensfun library?**

I want this for Darktable, which I think it's using lens fun database (according to [lensfun website](https://lensfun.github.io/)). But it don't detect that lens with calibration module.

Comment: No need to update lensfun itself, you can ask it to update its database , see [here](https://wilson.bronger.org/lensfun/lensfun-update-data.html) for instructions. Other wise you can use `yum info {package )` to list the version of an installed package.

Comment: @xenoid but the database isn't remote, isn't it? So it in to be installed and if I have old I need to update. Calling `lensfun‑update‑data` don't work - file not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how to check the lensfun version, but you can update the lensfun database using the following command:

```
$ lensfun-update-data
```

Please note that you must have the `lensfun-tools` package installed in order for the above command to work. `lensfun-tools` can be installed with this command:

```
$ sudo dnf install lensfun-tools
```